# SQL - Join two tables on column with similar values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two address tables but am having trouble because they are not similar on the street name when the street is numeric. E.g. When the first table street name is equal to '2nd' the second table street name is equal to '2'.  So, the tag at the end of the street is excluded from the second table. The tables have over one hundred thousand rows.  If necessary I could add the tag to the end of the street, but I can't think of any good ways to do that either.

Here is my code so far:

```
select * from address a
inner join mai_address ma on ma.hse_nbr=a.number and a.street=ma.street
```

The query doesn't include any streets with numbers because of this problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which database are you using?Also,can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Remove all non-numeric characters in the comparison?

Comment: I'm using ms sql server

Comment: Yes, using a function to remove all non-numeric characters might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you're going to be able to add that kind of logic into your database is to create a function to strip out the text you don't want.  However, joining two tables on a field wrapped in a function would be very inefficient.

A better solution would be to create the function but use it to update a new field in both tables and join on that table.  This could be done on a trigger

ie:

```
create trigger dbo.address_update
on dbo.address
after insert, update
as
begin
  update address a
  set    processed_street = ProcessStreet(street)
  join   inserted i
  on     i.unique_field = a.unique_field;
end;
```

Comment: The main reason I want to join the tables is to create a new column on one of the tables with a column from the other table.  This query will only be used one time, therefore efficiency shouldn't really be an issue.  If I were executing this query many times this would certainly make sense, so I'm giving you an up arrow. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

> Select *
>
> ```
>   from address 
>
>       inner join mai_address on dbo.f1(mai_address.hse_nbr) = address.street
> ```

And the function f1(@str) should return the left-side digits of the "@str" parameter (until reaches a non-digit or end of string). Something like this:

> create function dbo.f1(@str Varchar(10)) returns varchar(10) as
>
> ```
>   Begin 
>   define @str2 varchar(10)
>   define @i int
>   set @str2 = ''
>     set @i = 1
>     while ((@i <= len(@str)) and (substring(@str, @i, @i) between '0' and '9'))
>         begin
>         @str2 = concat(@str2, substring(@str, @i, @i))
>         set @i = @i + 1
>         end
>     return @str2
> end
> ```

Comment: I used a function to eliminate the text in any value that included a number and joined the table using this function.  What does the function in this answer exactly do?  FYI...See my answer below.

Comment: f1() in this solution extracts and returns the number that may be followed by one or more characters.

Comment: That would do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

```
CREATE Function [fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters](@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
 BEGIN
  WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText) > 0
 BEGIN
    SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strText), 1, '')
 END
    RETURN @strText
 END
```

Then to join I did this:

```
select * from address a
inner join mai_address ma on ma.hse_nbr=a.number and (a.street=ma.street OR dbo.fnRemoveNonNumericCharacters(ma.street)=a.street)
and (ma.unit_nbr=a.apt OR (ma.unit_nbr IS NULL AND a.apt IS NULL))
order by a.number
```

I used the function to revise the column value so it didn't include text.  I also used an or to take join on the street names that didn't include numbers.

Thanks for the great ideas!

Comment: You might want to mark this as the answer so others will find it.